# How to get only numerical key value pair from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I have a Json data like this

```
{
   "info":[
      {
         "Name":"Noob Here",
         "Major":"Language",
         "Sex":"Male",
         "English":"15",
         "Japanese":"5",
         "Calculus":"0",
         "Geometry":"20"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Noob Here",
         "Major":"Calculus",
         "Sex":"Female",
         "English":"0.5",
         "Japanese":"40",
         "Calculus":"20",
         "Geometry":"05"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to get only the key value pair where the value is numerical data.

Expected output

```
{
"English":"15",
"Japanese":"5",
"Calculus":"0",
 "Geometry":"20"
},
{
 "English":"0.5",
"Japanese":"40",
"Calculus":"20",
"Geometry":"05"
}
```

Is there any plugins for that or should i write long jquery code for it using regex?.

Comment: How did you generate this json? can you put that code?

Comment: its just json file hardcoded.

Comment: I dont think there is any plugins for that. You will have to loop though the json list and remove unwanted items

Comment: BTW, JSON can store numbers natively, you don't have to store them as strings, e.g. `"English": 0.5` (no quotes around the number). If you are able to do this yourself in your JSON file, you can just use `typeof value === 'number'` to identify them in your JavaScript.

Comment: you dont need to put quotes for numbers. you can simply write them without quotes. and this does not seem to be valid json format.

Comment: @jokeyrhyme thanx. Let me try it

Comment: @Sangeeta: its a valid format i checked it using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @SreekeshOkky have a look at my solution too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

used jquery `isNumeric` to find if numeric or not.. then playing with the objects and array..you need two loops to get the objects...

here you go..

```
var finalObj={};  //this is final output object
var info = [];  //array to push to finalObj
$.each(data.info,function(i,v){
  var object={};
  $.each(v,function(i1,val1){
    if($.isNumeric(val1)){

        object[i1]=val1
    }
  });
  info.push(object);
});
finalObj['info']=info;
console.log(finalObj);
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/en843/)

Answer (score 2):

you can parse the value with `parseInt` and if it is integer than select it.

test is equal to the json object to posted.

```
var obj = test.info[0];
for (var key in obj) {
if(!isNaN(parseInt(obj[key]))){
    alert(JSON.stringify(key));
         }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/gQfAN/

Answer (score 2):

You can write a helper function. Just pass in your Json object and loop through each of the fields. The regex is straight forward.

```
var regex = new RegExp("\d*\.?\d"); 
var result = regex.test("yourvalue");
```

If result is true, it is a number. compile your results and return a Json object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var data={
    "info":[
          {
             "Name":"Noob Here",
             "Major":"Language",
             "Sex":"Male",
             "English":"15",
             "Japanese":"5",
             "Calculus":"0",
             "Geometry":"20"
          },
          {
             "Name":"Noob Here",
             "Major":"Calculus",
             "Sex":"Female",
             "English":"0.5",
             "Japanese":"40",
             "Calculus":"20",
             "Geometry":"05"
          }
       ]
};
var newarr=[];


$(data.info).each(function(index,value){
    arr=new Object();
    $(Object.keys(value)).each(function(ind,val){
        if($.isNumeric(value[val]))
        {
            arr[val]=value[val];
        }
    });
    newarr.push(arr);

});
console.log(newarr);
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/RyVds/2/

To check `Object.keys()` Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff688127%28v=vs.94%29.aspx and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the keys on each object and try parseInt the value. It will return NaN if it's a string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.info.length; i++) {
  var tmp = {};
  keys = Object.keys(obj.info[i]);
  console.log(keys);
  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    if (parseInt(obj.info[i][keys[j]])) {
      tmp[keys[j]] = obj.info[i][keys[j]];
    }
  }
```

Full code is on a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wXBKd/1/